# Remote Desktop from Mac to Windows, screen resolution setting

Tags: windows-10, mac, remote-desktop, resolution

The screen resolution looks very weird to me when using Remote Desktop on Mac (from Apple store) to Windows, as the characters looks really tiny --

- My Windows' screen resolution is 1920 x 1200, everything looks normal whether connected locally or remotely from another window using a 1920 x 1200 display
- My new 16-inch MacBook Pro has a native resolution of 3072 x 1920

Thus `1920 x 1200` will/should only occupies a small portion of `3072 x 1920` of my Mac screen. But I found it is not the case. Even when I force my Remote Desktop on Mac to use a `1680 x 1050` resolution, the characters are still really tiny, even after I strength the windows size to as big as possible.

This doesn't make sense and is so weird to me. Maybe the DPI plays an important role, I don't know. But,

How to keep my Windows' 1920 x 1200 resolution while make characters looks normal in my Mac's Remote Desktop session?

Comment: Just to be clear, exactly which remote desktop software are you running on your Mac?

Comment: I'm guessing your remote desktop client software is not properly savvy to how macOS handles "retina" high resolution displays (other OSes might call this "HiDPI"). Your 16-inch MBP's native resolution is 3072 x 1920, but in the default retina scaling mode, any app that doesn't know that there's more than one pixel per "point" is going to think it's 1792 x 1120. So a 1920 x 1200 image should only take up about two-thirds of the width and height of the screen for any retina-savvy app, but a non-retina-savvy app would think the 1920 x 1200 image would need to be scaled down to fit full screen.

Comment: Thanks @Spiff, _"a non-retina-savvy app would think the 1920 x 1200 image would need to be scaled down to fit full screen"_, yes, it seems to be the case for the Windows Remote Desktop on Mac (from Apple store). It stared OK, until I tried to change the Mac default font size to larger, then the windows just scaled down. Even after I restored to "default", the windows just remains scaled down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added quite recently was a new option - Optimise for Retina displays
This is on v10.5, I'm not certain what version added it.

[image]

Untested as all the displays here are the same, standard 27" 1440p screens.